# Android configuration errors

Tags: android, photoeditorsdk

I am trying to configure the photoeditorSDK for Android, however I need to limit the tools that are presented to the user.  I want only the Text and Brush tools to be available (and my license is for these functions only).

Let me preface with I don't do much java programming - so this is a stretch.

I am trying to add the code from https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/guides/android/v5/introduction/configuration however it is giving me compile errors.  After adding the required imports, it is still giving me compile errors on the line

```
config.setTools(tools);
```

The error is the following:

> Error:(92, 27) error: no suitable method found for setTools(ArrayList)
>   method PESDKConfig.setTools(ArrayList) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; ArrayList cannot be converted to ArrayList)
>   method PESDKConfig.setTools(ToolConfigInterface...) is not applicable
>   (varargs mismatch; ArrayList cannot be converted to ToolConfigInterface)

I am wondering if it is a version issue - in the build.grade, it looks like I am adding version 4 (although referenced from version 5 documentation here - https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/guides/android/v5/introduction/getting_started)

```
compile 'ly.img.android:photo-editor-sdk:4.0.1'
```

Here's my questions:
1. How the heck do I determine the latest version of the SDK?
2. Why do I have to add code to reflect the tools that should show on the bar - my license already does this doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your request. You're right, there is actually a mistake in our documentation. The latest version of the SDK is **5.0.8** and you can find it in our documentations sidebar under Resources -> Releases:

https://artifactory.9elements.com/artifactory/imgly/ly/img/android/photo-editor-sdk/

Try:

```
compile 'ly.img.android:photo-editor-sdk:5.0.8‘
```

to get our latest SDK. Your code looks fine though. If you have further questions, just let me know!